# If the earth is sentient and can communicate with humans, shouldn't humans in general have more respect for its well-being?

Tags: society, planets, humans

Someday in the far future, when creatures are born from sentience modules that can be easily embedded into other living, non-sentient, or even non-living objects, humans became capable of communicating with pretty much anything, creating a truly intelligent internet of things and not a single entity is controlling it - not even us.

*We've figured out how the soul works, hardcoded it into the smallest computer we know, wrapped it up with a nice little object-specific shell interface, provided it with whatever renewable power works well with the interface, and just handed it to anything, anywhere, anytime, anyone we want.*

***You want a pet rock? Here you go. You want to marry it/him/her? Sure, why not. You wanna have kids with it/him/her? Uh. that's a bit problematic but, sure. Why the hell not? Wait. Are you a Vacuum Cleaner 3000 or a Vacuum Cleaner X-series? Because of you're one or the other, we might have to ask you to talk to different papers first.***

Giving away souls like its Halloween and everything your eyes can see are trick-or-treating sounds like a lot of fun, until you realize your toilet bowl can have the same rights as you have.

And the fun goes out the window when the whole planet just earned its own human-derived consciousness. Now, we might have known it before and didn't really thought about it that much, but now that our planet, volcanic zits and underwater ridges and all, has the same rights as we are, speaking the same language we do and maybe more, how are we going to respect each other?

Comment: The premises are a tad confusing. "when creatures are born from sentience modules that can be easily embedded into other living, non-sentient, or even non-living objects"...HUH?

Comment: So instead of just spreading intelligent life to the stars, we endow everything with smarts.   Everything except of course for toilets, because that would be... cruel.

Comment: If you have sentient humanlike minds in computers, there isn't any good reason to glue them in random places. Put them in a server room. Or into a robotic body with a useful range of actuators.

Answer (score 2):

Unless along the way to modularizing consciousness, we also learned to enhance its weak points, strengthening our tolerance, kindness and integrity, the distribution of consciousness out into the inanimate world would just expand the blood bath.

We live in a universe where to the best of our knowledge, only a few billion intelligent beings exist, and yet every day we despise, abuse and murder each other.

Add a few trillion non-humans with our style of intelligence and our worst post-singularity apocalyptic tales will become a reality.  [Maximum Overdrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_Overdrive), anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry have you met humans? We're at least as horrible to each other as we are to anything else, if not worse. The more like us we make the world the more porrly we'll treat it. I find it highly unlikely that Earth communicating with us will make much difference to how we relate to her.

> Mother nature, she can take us or leave us.
>
> We told her we loved her but she didn't believe us.
>
> We've got this planet of ours running a fever.
>
> She tried to warn us but we didn't believe her.

Not my words but they do tell the tale of humanity's relationship with our home, what makes you think mother Earth would waste words on us if she could talk to us directly. I certainly wouldn't in her position.